# ODBC Connection to SYBASE ASE using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sybase, sap-ase

Could you please help me with a recommended package to connect to Sybase ASE using python 3.6
I heard about sybpydb but I couldn't  find it online. 
Could you please recommend the optimum way to build this connection

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to connect Sybase ASE. I have tried and  connected successfully for Sybase ASE16 from Python 3.7.

```
import pyodbc
user = "user_name" 
passwd = "Password"
host = "server_name"
db = "database_name"
port = "port"
driver="Adaptive Server Enterprise"
#driver="FreeTDS"
query="select count (*) from emp"

print(datetime.datetime.now())
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, server=host, database=db,port = prt,uid=user, pwd=passwd) 
print(conn)    
cursor = conn.cursor()    
cursor.execute(query)    
row = cursor.fetchall()    
print(row)    
conn.close()
```

Comment: I'm sure I am breaking protocol, but thanks for this answer.  Quite useful

Comment: Im always getting tihs pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft]

Comment: Does not work for me!
Using: pyodbc.connect(driver="Adaptive Server Enterprise", server="x34akj67d.dev.com", port=6100, database="db_firmforall", uid="batman", pwd="robin") ... Getting error:[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Answer (score -1):

We are using pyodbc to connect to ASE databases.

```
def SetDbConnection(self, DefaultDb='master') :
   self.DbConnection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=freetds;SERVER=%s;PORT=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;TDS_Version=5.0;' % (self.ServerAdress, self.ServerPor
t, self.User, self.Pwd, DefaultDb),unicode_results=True,autocommit=True)
```

Comment: Error: [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)